# Discarded UDP datagram over MTU size with IPv6

Tags: udp, ipv6, icmp, arp

I've found out that when I send an UDP datagram that gets fragmented (over 1452 bytes with MTU=1500), according to tcpdump, all the fragments are received on the target machine but then no message is received on the socket. This happens only with IPv6 addresses (both global and link-local), with IPv4 everything works as expected (and with non-fragmented datagrams as well).
As the datagram is discarded, there is this ICMP6 message:

```
05:10:59.887920 IP6 (hlim 64, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 69) 2620:52:0:105f::ffff:74 > 2620:52:0:105f::ffff:7b: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, destination unreachable, length 69, unreachable port[|icmp6]
```

There's some repeated neighbour solicitation/advertisements going on and I see that it gets to the ARP cache (via ip neigh).
One minute later I get another ICMP6 messages saying that the fragment has timeout out.

What's wrong with the settings? The reassembled packet should not be discarded, when it can be delivered, right? 
System is RHEL6 2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: And socket receive buffer size does not have any effect on that, I've set it for 64k.

Comment: Can you show us the code? Does the IPv6 work for UDP datagrams of a smaller size (non fragmented) or a TCP connection?

Comment: Yes, finally I've started to suspect the firewall as I have some problems with TCP as well. Regrettably, I am not root on the system so I can't look on iptables -L, I am waiting for an answer from the sysadmin.

Comment: Check your firewall and make sure it is properly stateful and that all the appropriate rules are stateful.